# Is it rolling over or just rolling?

Tags: word-request

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OkoT9JLuPIU

"The children were rolling over on the floor."

Does this phrase describe what they're doing? I am wondering if it's "rolling over", "rolling" or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are simply "rolling".

To "roll over" is a phrasal verb that includes a resulting state,
**over**, which means to be inverted after rolling.

(Of course, *rolling over* twice means that you return to your original, uninverted state. You could also say of the children that they are rolling over again and again, but just **rolling** describes what they are doing.)